# using display-frame-alist to force switch to buffer

Tags: frames, focus, display-buffer-alist

Could someone please explain how to use default-frame-alist  to make list-buffers switch to the resulting results buffer? list-buffers uses display-buffer so I am thinking that display-buffer-alist is the object I should be tweaking to ensure that the buffer "*Buffer List*" gets focus via switch-to-buffer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end the answer was straightforward enough: create my own function to do just that with the correct calling interface:

```
(defun my-switch-to-buffer-list (buffer alist) 
  (select-window  (display-buffer-use-some-window buffer alist)))
```

The custom addition for display-frame-alist:

```
'(display-buffer-alist '(("\\*Buffer List\\*" (my-switch-to-buffer-list))))
```

I don't think there is a way to attach a lambda in the custom interface so this seems a reasonable solution.  Something like help-window-select would seem helpful.